# Windows 7, GTX 750, Dell 2408WFP: powering off display disconnects the display from the card

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I have the following monitors attached to my EVGA GeForce GTX 750 (2 GB):

- Dell 2408WFP connected via DisplayPort (monitor 1)
- Dell 2408WFP connected via HDMI (monitor 2)
- Dell 2007FP connected via DVI-D (monitor 3)

[image: screencap of my monitor layout]

If I turn off monitor 1 using the power switch, the monitor completely disconnects from the computer; I hear the device disconnected sound and the monitors rearrange themselves, with monitor 3 becoming monitor 1. Turning off monitors 2 and 3 have no such effect - the monitors are still visible to Windows.

It's also worth noting that monitor 1 does *not* disconnect from the computer when Windows turns the monitors off after 20 minutes - it falls asleep like it should.

Is there any way to fix this? I would prefer an actual fix as opposed to a workaround like using [Wizmo](https://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm) to control the monitor's power states.

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 with the NVIDIA 353.06 drivers. (For what it's worth, this problem occurred with the 350.12 drivers as well.)

Comment: Does it change with which monitor is plugged into the DisplayPort?

Comment: @MichaelFrank yes - whichever 2408WFP is plugged into the DisplayPort will exhibit this behavior. (the 2007FP does not have a DisplayPort input.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning DisplayPort monitor off disables monitor completely](http://superuser.com/questions/630555/turning-displayport-monitor-off-disables-monitor-completely)