# Windows on second monitor move to primary monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

After a recent Windows update, windows in my second monitor goes to the primary monitor when monitors goes to black. I do not have this problem before.

My two monitors are Asus (primary) and AOC (second), The video card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB (connect to primary monitor), and Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (connect to second monitor).

I know this is an old question and I tried solutions as following.

Solution 1: [Windows on second monitor moves to primary monitor after sleep/lock](https://superuser.com/questions/1292435/windows-on-second-monitor-moves-to-primary-monitor-after-sleep-lock)

I checked that there are no greyed out monitor in Device Manager.

[image: Screenshot of Device Manager]

Solution 2: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-movesresizes-windows-on-monitor-power/1653aafb-848b-464a-8c69-1a68fbd106aa

But as shown in the picture, I have multiple entries that confuse me. I'm not sure which entries I should change.

[image: Screenshot of Registry Editor]

Comment: Try re-installing the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I'm also having this issue but I have two different monitors. I'm running GeForce RTX 2080 with an Alienware as my primary and a Samsung as my second monitor. The primary is hooked up using the DisplayPort and the secondary is hooked up using HDMI. I'm wondering if my computer stops sending power to the second monitor when they go to sleep. The computer itself never sleeps or hibernates. I've tried a lot of things, including the two you've listed and even https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/discover/239683/displayport-autodetect-override-view-system-topology-on-desktop-cards/