# Application windows on HDMI connected second monitor reposition to primary monitor after sleep / lock

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, sleep

There are quite a few posts here about this issue, but almost all of them relate to monitors connected via Display Port. Many of them are suffering from the Rapid Hot Plug Detect that Microsoft was trying to fix last year. It's unclear to me if Microsoft has rolled out their fix for this in Windows 10 21H2 build 19044.1706 (the build I am running).

However, I believe my issue may be different than these other posts so making a new question here that is specific to HDMI connected monitors.

In this scenario, my 2nd monitor is connected using an HDMI <-> HDMI cable and the primary monitor is on a Display Port <-> DisplayPort cable.

The issue presents when both monitors sleep and are left for at least an extra 2-3 minutes after the monitor enters power save mode (due to a lack of signal) and then are woken up by moving the mouse.  The second monitor wakes up first and I can see my application windows still on that display (i.e. Skype, Signal, Slack, etc...) for about 1 second. Then the primary monitor wakes up, the second monitor flashes, and *THEN* the windows are moved to the primary monitor.

I have attempted all the various methods posted on Microsoft forums and here including:

- https://superuser.com/a/1292444/1195335
- https://superuser.com/a/1615106/1195335
- https://superuser.com/a/849327/1195335
- Rolled back my Nvidia driver back by 2 months to when I was not experiencing this issue and that did not have any effect.
- Switched from HDMI <-> HDMI to new high quality Display Port <-> HDMI cable

System configuration is:

- Windows 10 21H2 19044.1706
- EVGA RTX 2060 SUPER XC 8GB
- LG 27GN650 Display Port to Display Port
- LG 24MK430 HDMI to HDMI

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to low rep and I realise this is an old post, but I've been struggling with this forever, and I've finally come across a solution:

https://github.com/kangyu-california/PersistentWindows
This script promises to keep track of and restore window and taskbar positions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1151399)