# Properly locking Windows 10 taskbar to the proper monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar, displayport

So I've been struggling with this issue for quite a while. At first I thought it was a combination of DisplayPort and an HDMI monitor, but now that I have 2 monitors with a DisplayPort the issue persists.

My situation:
I have 2 monitors. One is an AOC 24G1WG4, the other is my new LG 27GL83A-B and I'm running it as an extended setup.

As my primary monitor I have my LG and so my secondary monitor is the AOC. I have disabled the option that the taskbar is at all my monitors because I would only show the taskbar on my secondary monitor. When I unlock the taskbar and drag it to the secondary monitor and lock it again it stays there as long as I don't turn off the power for my monitors.

That being said when I switch off my monitors and turn it on again my taskbar gets moved to the primary monitor and it's still locked.

Now I have read various things, one reason could be because the LG is switching on quicker and so it becomes the primary another could be because of inactive devices.

I have tried a few open source tools to "fix" this issue, but to no avail. I'm wondering if anyone has had this issue and if there is a solution by now?

Looking forward to some tips to solve this issue as it's driving me insane :(

Comment: What happens if, while the config is as described above, you turn off and on only the primary monitor? If nothing changes, try then turning off/on the secondary monitor.

Comment: I have turned off the primary monitor first. When powering it on again it remained the same. However when I powered down the secondary monitor and switched it back on the problem occured (taskbar switched to the primary LG monitor).

When I switch off my monitors I switch them simultaneously both off and on (my way of eco mode :P)

Comment: I did some more research and found the solution to my problem. Previously I had only removed the configuration as it was the only one listed the that guide. Here's a guide that actually fixed it for me:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-reset-external-monitors-settings/b3a53cef-e54f-4410-b09e-6846fa297a3f

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, it seems that your problem is mostly with
DisplayPort. DisplayPort under Windows is implemented as a PNP device, differently
than VGA and DVI, in that when the monitor enters the sleep state Windows
treats it as if it were removed, even displacing its displayed windows
to other monitors. When the monitor wakes up, Windows treats it as a new device
being discovered. This behavior might be the cause of your problems.

Whenever you turn off the secondary monitor, Windows will move everything
to the primary monitor. It doesn't matter here if the primary monitor
is on or off.

If you can move the secondary monitor to DVI, this might be one solution.

Another solution which will prevent Windows from verifying the continued
presence of the DisplayPort monitors is to keep the EDID properties of the
DisplayPort monitors.

For this solution see these answers of mine :

- [GeForce GTX 980 Ti reverts to single monitor on wake up](https://superuser.com/a/1027641/8672)
- [Turning DisplayPort monitor off disables monitor completely](https://superuser.com/a/631691/8672)

Comment: Thanks, I've read something about EDID, but only found NVidea solutions. I'm running an RX5700 XT (Red Devil). The AMD EDID Emulation software doesn't seem to like my graphics card as it's giving me a message that my card isn't supported :(

Comment: You could possibly use a hardware solution - a fast search found [this candidate](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pass-Through-Emulator-splitters-Switches-Extenders/dp/B072JC9443?th=1). For software the situation is better on Windows, so is this your case?