# windows open on second screen, even when its powered off

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11

My Windows 11 installation does not disable the secondary screen when I turn it off. Windows remain open on the secondary screen while its turned off (in standby mode). Screen settings show the screen as connected, even when its turned off.

I am used to the behaviour that windows detects the turned off screen as disconnected and switches to single screen mode automatically.

I do *not* want to:

- disconnect any cable.
- disable/reenable the second screen manually, i.e. via screen settings or via [WIN] + P shortcut.

I want Windows to handle the screen connect/disconnect automatically. I want to be able to randomly turn on/off the second screen and I want Windows to use it only when it is turned on. When turned off, the windows that are open on the second screen should be moved to the primary screen, and when I open a new window, it should only ever be opened on the primary screen.

Is there some way to enable this desired behaviour in Windows 11?

I'm really annoyed about this changed behaviour. This did not appear before switching from windows 10 to 11 on the same hardware. Nothing has changed but the OS: same graphics card (NVIDIA Geforce GTX 960) and same screens. (2x Dell U2515H, 1. with Displayport, 2. with HDMI)

Comment: Is the monitor connected via DisplayPort or via HDMI?

Comment: @harrymc if you post an answer explaining the difference, i might upvote and accept it. HDMI connection was the problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application windows all move to main display after screens turn back on](https://superuser.com/questions/1640338/application-windows-all-move-to-main-display-after-screens-turn-back-on)

Comment: It does say how DisplayPort is different.

Comment: @harrymc The referenced answer does not refer to HDMI at all. It does explain why DP is different from VGA and DVI, both don't support EDID. But HDMI does support EDID just like DP, so no, the referenced answer does not provide an acceptable explanation.

Comment: You misunderstand, but no problem.

Comment: @harrymc i'd like to understand - please help me?

Comment: @harrymc from what i understand, the "detect power state of monitor" feature is based on EDID information, which is available both via DP and HDMI. Am I wrong?

Comment: HDMI & DVI are very similar and the EDID is only asked for some events like device-recognition after boot. Unlike them, DP is plug-and-play, so Windows regularly asks for the EDID as plugged-in status.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was the HDMI connection of the secondary screen. I switched both to DisplayPort and now Windows behaves as expected. But i'm quite sure this worked with HDMI too, back when DP wasn't a thing?