# Main monitor go blank when switching from Extend to Duplicate in Windows 11

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

In Windows 11 using Nvidia latest drivers (RTX 3060) I use two monitors in `Extend` with no issues. If I switch to `Duplicate`, the main monitor go blank (doesn't turn off). If I switch to `PC Screen Only` and then to `Duplicate`, it works fine. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Does this happen if you switch main/secondary ?

Comment: @harrymc it have the same behavior but on the same monitor (the now secondary). This one is connected with DP, and the other is HDMI.

Comment: So the problem is with the DisplayPort monitor?

Comment: @harrymc yes, the DP one go blank

Comment: Yes, that explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

DisplayPort acts as a PNP device, so turning off the monitor,
even for an instant, is treated as if it was removed and windows are
moved out and rearranged because Windows forgets this device,
until it is turned on again and is "discovered".

I don't know why in your computer changing the desktop mode between
Extend and Duplicate causes the hardware or the driver to think that
the DisplayPort is turned off, but this happens and needs to be solved,

A solution which will prevent Windows from verifying the continued
presence of a DisplayPort monitor and so to not detect that it's off,
is to keep a static copy of the
[Extended Display Identification Data (EDID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)
properties of the monitor, which is what Windows is reading when it
"discovers" this "new" monitor.

For this solution see these answers of mine (you are not the only one to
have had such a problem with DisplayPort):

- [GeForce GTX 980 Ti reverts to single monitor on wake up](https://superuser.com/a/1027641/8672)
- [Turning DisplayPort monitor off disables monitor completely](https://superuser.com/a/631691/8672)