# Windows 10 - Disable third monitor automatically when it's powered off

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

I have three monitor outputs from my video card: monitor 1, monitor 2, and a projector.

The Windows display settings looks like this:
[image]

If the projector is turned off, and I move my mouse to the right of the 2nd screen, it disappears and gets lost in the projector's view, even though the projector is turned off.

It's frustrating when I lose my pointer, but even worse when Windows is placing windows there, so I have to `alt+tab` + `win+left` to bring them back in. Some windows can't be moved with `win+left` so I have to turn on the projector, or pull the HDMI to get a hold of them.

- I know I can disable the monitor manually
- `win+P` can not disable one out of three monitors
- The projector is a BenQ 3D DLP W1070+

Is it possible to automatically disable the third monitor/projector in Windows if it's turned off?

Comment: What are the connections (HDMI, DisplayPort, VGA) ?

Comment: you **might** be able to find an answer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8a9b5aa7-fe33-4e6d-b39b-8ac80a21fdc2/disable-monitor-off-detection-how) (they are trying to turn off what you are trying to turn on)

Comment: @harrymc DP to HDMI (adapter). Albin: Thanks, I'll give it a read.

Comment: If you could use DP exclusively, this might solve the problem.

Comment: @harrymc I only have HDMI in on the monitor. How does DP work differently than HDMI in this case?

Comment: The DP detects monitor power-off as device removed, HDMI dosn't. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/631691/8672).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, DisplayPort between PC and projector would have disabled it at shutdown, but the projector is HDMI in only, so this is not possible, correct?

Comment: Would 3rd party software for display configuration profiles be a suitable solution for you?  I found [Monitor Profile Switcher](https://sourceforge.net/projects/monitorswitcher/) on SourceForge.  It's not entirely automatic, but it would save a few clicks reconfiguring your displays.

Comment: @Blaelph That's the best secondary solution so far, as the issue seems unsolvable.